# installation did not complete

Tags: 14.04

Am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 7. I followed the installation instructions for flash drive until it did prompt me to restart. I restarted immediately but on reboot it did not continue with the installation. It has not completed the installation since it still require the removable media to boot fully. Please help on what I did wrong and on what I can do to complete the installation successfully.

Comment: First recommendation: backup all of your datas.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with dual boot do you see grub boot menu in which boot options are there with Every operating system on your disk? If no then you should reinstall Ubuntu and If yes then do a boot repair using the live USB Flash drive you created to install Ubuntu

You can get more information about boot repair [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)